# Can a user get forecast access to the role above in the role hierarchy

Tags: sharing, role-hierarchy, forecast

```
Role A
  Role A1
  Role A2
  Role A3
Role B
  Role B1
  Role B2
Role C
  Role C1
```

Can a user in Role `C1` get forecast access to the role `A1`?

Answer (score 0):

Can they? Yes if other sharing rules give them such access.

However if you are in a private OWD model and previous admins have NOT added or installed any sharing grants that would pass your test case, then "No" the role hierarchy itself will not grant access to role members of the same level or beneath.  That kind of sharing would require use of an additional sharing tool, such as criteria-based sharing rules, apex sharing, or any other suitable sharing mechanism (teams grants, owd grants, profile grants, permission set grants, manual sharing grants, etc.  https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/04/salesforce-data-security-model-explained-visually.html)

Depending on the salesforce edition used, there may be about 20 different mechanisms that an admin can employ to share records, and that may change (https://s3.amazonaws.com/forcetalks/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/18232651/sharerecords.png)

Role Hierarchy is just one mechanism for controlling record sharing. OWD, Sharing Rules, Apex Sharing, Teams, and other settings offer additional ways to control record-sharing (including who can see what).

Look across the entire 'sharing model', and tools within, such as OWD, etc, before declaring with certainty 'who can see what'